# Proof of inequality involving multiplicative function?

Tags: number-theory, induction, multiplicative-function

The identity below seems true for the examples I've considered. I thought I had proven it using induction but found a mistake and removed my attempted proof since it is not helpful. Given:

$P(z)$ is the product of primes less than $z,$

$\nu(d)$ is the number of distinct prime divisors of $d$,

$\omega(\cdot)\geq 0$ is multiplicative, $m$ is an integer $\geq 1,$

> can we prove/disprove
>
> $\sum_{d|P(z),\nu(d) \leq m} \omega(d)\leq (1+\sum_{p|P(z)}\omega(p))^m\hspace{7mm}?$

Comment: $\omega(d)$ is multiplicative and non-negative ?

Comment: @user1952009: edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider $\omega(p_1p_2...p_k)$, and how you could break this down using multiplicativity. Then see if this might match with a term (or combination of terms) on the right hand side.

Comment: you should post the answer yourself if you found it with the help of that hint

Comment: Terms in the binomial expressions on the left with m factors are all covered by terms in mth powers of the expression on the right. Once we see the LHS can be written as a product of binomials we can compare the two sides. Your hint prompted me to look at the LHS again. The key (which I forgot or didn't know) is that $n=p_k\#,~\binom{k}{m}$ is the number of squarefree divisors of n having $\nu(d)=m.$